# PATH and exec-path set, but emacs does not find executable

Tags: emacs, dot-emacs

My .emacs contains

```
(setenv "PATH" (concat ".:/usr/texbin:/opt/local/bin" (getenv "PATH")))
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '(".:/usr/texbin:/opt/local/bin")))

(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp")
(require 'tex-site)
(load "auctex.el" nil t t)
(load "preview-latex.el" nil t t)
```

/usr/texbin is where latex/pdflatex/.. are located.
/opt/local/bin/ is where gs can be found.

And yet when I run preview-at-point, which apparently needs both latex and gs, I get

```
Preview-DviPS finished at Thu Dec 22 11:25:46
DviPS sentinel: Searching for program: No such file or directory, gs
```

which means that latex could be found all right, but not gs.

I am not sure whether setting exec-path is necessary, perhaps PATH is enough, but I've set it as a debugging measure.

Why can emacs not find gs even though the directory it's in is in both PATH and exec-path?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

If you're setting `$PATH` inside your Emacs, you might well be on OS X. GUI applications are not started via your shell, so they see different environment variables.

Here's a trick which I use to ensure the `$PATH` inside Emacs is the same one I see if I fire up a terminal (**but see "update" below**):

```
(defun set-exec-path-from-shell-PATH ()
  "Set up Emacs' `exec-path' and PATH environment variable to match that used by the user's shell.

This is particularly useful under Mac OSX, where GUI apps are not started from a shell."
  (interactive)
  (let ((path-from-shell (replace-regexp-in-string "[ \t\n]*$" "" (shell-command-to-string "$SHELL --login -i -c 'echo $PATH'"))))
    (setenv "PATH" path-from-shell)
    (setq exec-path (split-string path-from-shell path-separator))))
```

Then simply call the `set-exec-path-from-shell-PATH` function, perhaps from your Emacs init file. I keep that code [on github](https://github.com/purcell/emacs.d/blob/master/init-exec-path.el), BTW.

**Update: this code has now been improved and published as an elisp library called [exec-path-from-shell](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell); installable packages are available in [MELPA](http://melpa.milkbox.net/).**

Comment: I am indeed on OSX, and loading PATH and exec-path from the shell would be very nice. Yet `string-rtrim` is not found (by neither emacs 22 nor 23). Is it your own function?

Comment: Ah, yes, it's my own function: I'll edit the answer to fix this.

Comment: Greetings.. If you have a chance, please update your answer. It would be very handy for us emacs/Mac users. As you identified, the question is really relevant mostly to Mac folks, so if you have enough points, please migrate the queston to apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Calaf The answer had already been updated as promised. I don't get involved with the other stackexchange sites, and the correct home for Emacs questions is a perenially contentious topic, so I'll decline to move the question.

Comment: No problem about moving the answer. I personally prefer a single site with osx as a tag anyway, though the current convention is otherwise. About the answer: it is not usable because string-rtrim is undefined, as I mentioned earlier in this thread.

Comment: Yes, but as you can see above, I edited the answer in December to remove the use of that function. :-)

Comment: I see. Thanks. I had missed the update. Can you explain something? The standard place for updating the PATH env variable is in .bash_profile. MacPorts, for one, updates that file directly. But .bash_profile is not run before emacs is launched, and so any modifications to PATH there are missed.

Comment: Yes. GUI apps are not launched via your shell, so they don't see any of the shell's environment settings. If you start Emacs by running `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs` from your shell, it will probably see the correct $PATH. OSX uses an `environment.plist` file to determine the environment vars seen by GUI apps, but my method above avoids the need to edit both that file *and* `.bash_profile`.

Comment: @sanityinc It is conventional for exec-directory to be the final element of exec-path. Maybe add that to your code?

Comment: @hruvulum Thanks for the pointer -- the "polished" version of this code now does exactly that: https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell

Comment: The package `exec-path-from-shell` adds all the right things to `exec-path`, but `eshell` still does not find executables or executable scripts from those directories. `GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.18.9)` What more needs to be done?

Comment: @Zelphir `exec-path-from-shell` normally sets `eshell-path-env`. If you want help, feel free to file an issue on the [repo](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell).

Comment: Mac OS X user here: I personally find infuriating this gotcha of GUI applications not having the same $PATH as terminal. I have been painstakingly manually setting the `path-to-shell` variable for every single inferior shell I'm using in emacs, assuming that emacs not capturing my $PATH was just a feature, not a bug (though looking back, I do seem to recall not having to do this on Ubuntu)

Comment: `open /Applications/Emacs.app/`

Answer (score 12):

Try replacing the second line with this:

```
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/usr/texbin" "/opt/local/bin")))
```

Comment: That solves the `gs` problem, but there is now another problem, which seems related to the permissions of the file generated by gs. Let me ask that question separately.

Answer (score 1):

I hit a similar problem, but with a correct PATH, including trailing ´:´. It turned out the internal emacs shell program was missing, resulting in a ´Searching for program: No such file or directory´ message. 
Fixed with

```
(setq shell-file-name "bash").
```

Answer (score -3):

It appears you're missing a path separator `:` at the end of your path string.

Comment: IOW, use ".:/usr/texbin:/opt/local/bin:" (note `:` at end).

Comment: After adding a terminating path separator (and restarting emacs) I still get the same error.

Comment: No! Exactly don't do this. This is for shell PATH's not for the exec-path variable which is just a list.