# Emacs ada gnatmake: command not found

Tags: macos, emacs, ada, gnat

I'm using Mac OS X Mavericks
I have installed gnat GPL and set the PATH correctly so gnat make works in the terminal. I have also added the path to .bashrc, and gnat make works in emacs shell, but in ADA mode if i do C-c C-c I get the following message:

```
/bin/bash: gnatmake: command not found
```

Comment: You should set both environment variable `PATH` and `exec-path` variable. I recommend you to use exec-path-from-shell. https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell . It is useful for setting environment variables between Emacs and shell.

Comment: @syohex, that should be an answer! (also reference [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8609349/40851))

Comment: @syohex agreed, should be the answer

Comment: Answered as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should set both environment variable PATH and exec-path variable. I recommend you to use exec-path-from-shell. https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell . It is useful for setting environment variables between Emacs and shell