# exec-path set correctly, but emacs does not find executable

Tags: emacs

I am trying to export an org document to html, using the program `bibtex2html`, which I have installed:

```
$ which bibtex2html
/usr/bin/bibtex2html
```

Accordingly, I checked the `exec-path` variable in emacs:

```
("/app/bin" "/usr/bin" "/home/sean/.var/app/org.gnu.emacs/data/node/bin" "/home/sean/.var/app/org.gnu.emacs/data/cargo/bin" "/home/sean/.var/app/org.gnu.emacs/data/python/bin" "/app/libexec/emacs/27.2/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/")
```

However, when I run the export command, which calls `bibtex2html`, I get the following message:
`Searching for program: no such file or directory, bibtex2html`

I'm at a bit of a loss here. I tried using https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell, which I found from the answers at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606954/path-and-exec-path-set-but-emacs-does-not-find-executable), but it did not help.

More specifics, as requested:
I am trying to use `org-export-dispatch` to export the document to an HTML file. I am using doom emacs, and my keybindings for this command are `SPC m e h h`. Document export succeeds if I do not try to include a bibliography. I have `(require 'ox-bibtex')`, which  in my `doom/config.el` file, as such:

```
(use-package! org-roam-bibtex
  :after org-roam
  :config
  (require 'org-ref)
  (require 'ox-bibtex))
```

I call `ox-bibtex` according to [the documentation in its code](https://github.com/yyr/org-mode/blob/master/contrib/lisp/ox-bibtex.el)c, by including the following line at the end of my org document:

```
#+BIBLIOGRAPHY: bibfilename stylename optional-options
```

Comment: That sounds strange.  Is this all local, or is Tramp involved in this workflow somehow?  If it is, see `C-h v tramp-remote-path` -- although `/usr/bin` should be present in pretty much *any* default path, so I doubt it's that either.

Comment: Were you running `which bibtex2html` from inside Emacs?  If not, test `M-! which bibtex2html`.  Also run `M-: (executable-find "bibtex2html")` which will use `exec-path`.  Also triple-check that there isn't a typo somewhere.

Comment: Last questions for now: Where is Emacs getting "bibtex2html" from?  Where is that configured?  Sanity-check that.  And please update the question with specific details of how you are (attempting to) export this.  Specifically which library, command, key sequence, etc, are you using.

Comment: Thanks phils. I run Tramp occasionally, but it is not involved in this case.

I was running `which bibtex2html` from the terminal, not inside emacs.  From emacs, I get a similar message: `which: no bibtex2html in (/app/bin:/usr/bin:/home/sean/.var/app/org.gnu.emacs/data/node/bin:/home/sean/.var/app/org.gnu.emacs/data/cargo/bin:/home/sean/.var/app/org.gnu.emacs/data/python/bin)`.  `M-: (executable-find "bibtex2html")` returns `nil`. Strange indeed! 

I will update the question with specific details now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem. The error was that I was using the flatpak version of Emacs. Flatpak sandboxes applications in such a way to prevent accessing external files (in this case, `bibtex2html`).

To fix, I uninstalled the flatpak version, and re-installed using [https://launchpad.net/~kelleyk/+archive/ubuntu/emacs](https://launchpad.net/%7Ekelleyk/+archive/ubuntu/emacs)

Comment: This isn't the first time I've seen a problem traced back to a flatpak Emacs build, so you're probably also saving yourself some other future pain by avoiding it.